# Can someone explain me what is the "LeftFirst" Boolean flag they have defined in the ecmaScript specification

Tags: javascript, relational-operators, ecmascript-2020

Can someone explain to me what is the `LeftFirst` Boolean flag? when reading the [EcmaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators) about [relational-operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators" relational-operators definition in ECMAScript") and  [Abstract Relational Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) I found something like the `LeftFirst` Boolean Flag it either becomes `true` or `false` but I don't know what is the use of it and for what it's there can someone clearly explain me what is the purpose of the `LeftFirst` Boolean flag and why it is used in the specification the explanation they have given is not much clear I want to know what is the use of it The `leftFirst` Boolean Flag and why it's used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noted, it's one of the inputs to the [Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison). Its sole purpose is to determine which operand the comparison algorithm is passed to ToPrimitive first, the one on the left (*leftFirst* = true) or the one on the right (*leftFirst* = false). The reason is that the Abstract Relational Comparison always does a `<` comparison, but it's also used when evaluating `>` expressions (with the operands reversed). So when handling a `>`, it needs to be told to use ToPrimitive on the right-hand operand first.

You can see it used in the first step of the algorithm:

> 1. If the *LeftFirst* flag is **true**, then
>
>    - Let *px* be ? ToPrimitive(*x*, hint Number).
>    - Let *py* be ? ToPrimitive(*y*, hint Number).
> 2. Else,
>      
>    NOTE: The order of evaluation needs to be reversed to preserve left to right evaluation.
>
>    - Let *py* be ? ToPrimitive(*y*, hint Number).
>    - Let *px* be ? ToPrimitive(*x*, hint Number).

Also in the description:

> The flag is used to control the order in which operations with potentially visible side-effects are performed upon *x* and *y*. It is necessary because ECMAScript specifies left to right evaluation of expressions.

For example, if you look at [the `<` and `>` operations](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), the `&lt;` operation does:

> 5. Let *r* be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison *lval < rval*.

That uses the default value of *leftFirst*, which is `true`. So `lval` is passed through ToPrimitive before `rval`.

But the `>` operation does:

> 5. Let *r* be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison *rval* < *lval* with *LeftFirst* equal to **false**.

Notice that it does `rval < lval`, not `lval > rval`. But it uses *leftFirst* = `false` because it's important that the *right* operand be passed through ToPrimitive before the left operand, since the real operation is `lval > rval`, so `lval` should be passed through ToPrimitive first.

---

In a comment you've said:

> Thank you very much i got to know why if `<` operator is `LeftFirst true` then why `<=` is also not `LeftFirst true` and why if `>` operator is `LeftFirst false` the `>=` operator is also not `LeftFirst false`

It's definitely a bit confusing. The reason that `<` and `<=` don't match (and `>` and `>=` don't match) is that the `<=`/`>=` operators invert the result of the Abstract Relational Comparison (ARC). So:

- `lval < rval` does:

  ```
  let r = ARC(lval < rval, leftFirst = true);
  return r === undefined ? false : r; // Returns what ARC returned (but
                                      // turns `undefined` into `false`)
  ```
- `lval <= rval` does

  ```
  let r = ARC(rval < lval, leftFirst = false);
  return r === undefined ? true : !r; // Returns the *inverse* of what ARC
                                      // returned (and turns `undefined`
                                      // into `true`)
  ```
- `lval > rval` does:

  ```
  let r = ARC(rval < lval, leftFirst = false);
  return r === undefined ? false : r; // Returns what ARC returned (but
                                      // turns `undefined` into `false`)
  ```
- `lval >= rval` does:

  ```
  let r = ARC(lval < rval, leftFirst = true);
  return r === undefined ? true : !r; // Returns the *inverse* of what ARC
                                      // returned (and turns `undefined`
                                      // into `true`)
  ```

---

A a final note, let's consider this:

```js
const obj = {
    get lval() {
        console.log("obj.lval was evaluated");
        return {
            valueOf() {
                console.log("lval was passed through ToPrimitive");
                return 42;
            }
        };
    },
    get rval() {
        console.log("obj.rval was evaluated");
        return {
            valueOf() {
                console.log("rval was passed through ToPrimitive");
                return 24;
            }
        };
    }
};

console.log("Using >");
const result1 = obj.lval > obj.rval;
// "obj.lval was evaluated"
// "obj.rval was evaluated"
// "lval was passed through ToPrimitive"
// "rval was passed through ToPrimitive"
console.log(result1);
// true

console.log("Using <");
const result2 = obj.lval < obj.rval;
// "obj.lval was evaluated"
// "obj.rval was evaluated"
// "lval was passed through ToPrimitive"
// "rval was passed through ToPrimitive"
console.log(result2);
// false
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

The output you see from that is this:

Using >
obj.lval was evaluated
obj.rval was evaluated
lval was passed through ToPrimitive
rval was passed through ToPrimitive
true
Using

Here's what happens to create that output for `>`:

1. The `obj.lval > obj.rval` expression is evaluated
2. The `>` [operator algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) is run:

   1. It evaluates `lval = obj.lval` (Steps 1 & 2), which causes the `"obj.lval was evaluated"` output
   2. It evaluates `rval = obj.rval` (Steps 3 & 4), which causes the `"obj.rval was evaluated"` output
   3. It calls ARC (Step 5): `ARC(obj.rval < obj.lval, leftFirst = false)`

      1. ARC recieves `obj.rval` as `x` and `obj.lval` as `y`
      2. ARC sees leftFirst = `false` and so it does:

         - `py = ToPrimitive(y)` (Step 2.b), which causes the `"lval was passed through ToPrimitive"` output
         - `px = ToPrimitive(x)` (Step 2.c), which causes the `"rval was passed through ToPrimitive"` output
      3. ARC returns `false`
3. The `>` operator inverts ARC's return value and returns `true`

Here's what happens to create the subsequent output for `<`:

1. The `obj.lval < obj.rval` expression is evaluated
2. The `<` [operator algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation) is run:

   1. It evaluates `lval = obj.lval` (Steps 1 & 2), which causes the `"obj.lval was evaluated"` output
   2. It evaluates `rval = obj.rval` (Steps 3 & 4), which causes the `"obj.rval was evaluated"` output
   3. It calls ARC (Step 5): `ARC(obj.lval < obj.rval)` (leftFirst defaults to true)

      1. ARC recieves `obj.lval` as `x` and `obj.rval` as `y`
      2. ARC sees leftFirst = `true` and so it does:

         - `px = ToPrimitive(x)` (Step 1.a), which causes the `"lval was passed through ToPrimitive"` output
         - `py = ToPrimitive(y)` (Step 1.b), which causes the `"rval was passed through ToPrimitive"` output
      3. ARC returns `false`
3. The `<` operator returns ARC's return value, `false`

Comment: but why it will have to do so with the `LeftFirst` Boolean Flag they could have just simpy explianed me this with the `>`

Comment: @Kevin - Using the *leftFirst* flag lets them describe the comparison operation purely in terms of `<`, which apparently they wanted to do. I don't know what the constraints are (which may have changed over time) that made them want to use that vs (for instance) a *lessThan* flag they used in Step 4(k), but there we are...

Comment: so this means that the same `Abstract Relational Comparison algorithm` `expr1 < expr2` is used to compare an operation like `expr1 > expr2` with `LeftFirst` being `false`. simply they use the same `<` operator with an expression like this `expr1 > expr2`. they use the `<` operator instead of `>` operator

Comment: @Kevin - Right. With `expr1 > expr2`, the Abstract Relational Comparison is asked to `expr2 < expr1` instead, but with *leftFirst* = `false`. See the quoted part after *"But the `>` operation does"* above. I've also reworded my paragraph after it to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much i got to know why if `<` operator is `LeftFirst` `true` then why  `<=` is also not `LeftFirst` `true` and why if `>` operator is `LeftFirst` `false` the `>=` operator is also not `LeftFirst` `false`

Comment: @Kevin - Ah, yeah. I've just added something about that, but I think you'd already figured it out.

Comment: But in the specification it's not mentioned that after the `LeftFirst` becomes `false` the right operand is evaluated first for an ex: `10 > 5` is executed `LeftFirst` being false so it's executed like `5 < 10` so in the specification they have not mentioned that the rightOperand(10) is evaluated first before the leftOperand(5) when the `5 < 10` is executed

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, they have, in the [sections linked above](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation). Under *"RelationalExpression:RelationalExpression>ShiftExpression"* it says (Step 5) *"Let r be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison rval < lval with LeftFirst equal to false."* Then the first two steps of ARC ensure evaluating `lval` first.

Comment: is this only for `objects` or is this rule applied for both `objects and primitives`

Comment: @Kevin - It applies to all operands, but it's only *observable* if those operands are objects; otherwise, it's purely internal and can't be observed. That's because the *initial* evaluation is done in the `>` operation itself. What ARC does is the ToPrimitive operation, which is a no-op if the thing being passed in is *already* a primitive.

Comment: but this user says something different about this i really dunno what here's the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60799820/can-someone-explain-what-exactly-the-leftfirst-booelan-flag-is-in-abstract-re

Comment: @Kevin - No, Pointy is saying what I said above. BTW, here's an example of observing the behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/n8rfeoza/ But I can see a couple of places in the answer where I said "evaluated," which is a bit imprecise. I've fixed them.

Comment: @Kevin - I've updated the end of the answer to walk through doing a `>` and a `<`, showing evaluation vs. ToP:rimitive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210107/discussion-between-kevin-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @Kevin - I think we've covered the ground fairly thoroughly at this point.

Comment: But in the `Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm` you can see when `LeftFirst` becomes false the right operand operand y is first passed to ToPrimitive before the left operand x is passed to ToPrimitive 

`If the LeftFirst flag is true, then
Let px be ? ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
Let py be ? ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
Else,
NOTE: The order of evaluation needs to be reversed to preserve left to right evaluation.
Let py be ? ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).
Let px be ? ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).`
can you explain About this a little to me pls it will be great

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, that's right, which is why it exists. Remember that in situations where ARC is called with *leftFirst* = `false`, the operation calling it has *reversed the operands*. In `a > b`, `>` calls ARC with `b < a` (not `a < b`) and *leftFirst* = `false`. That's why it passes that flag, so that `a` is run through ToPrimitive first.

Comment: Do you know why the `Abstract operation` `isStringPrefix(py, px)` returns `false` in ["Abstract Relational Comparison "](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison) `if isStringPrefix(py, px) is true return false` and can you explain me why the  `isStringPrefix()` is used what is it meant to do

Comment: @Kevin - The [definition of IsStringPrefix](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isstringprefix) seems fairly clear to me: *"The abstract operation IsStringPrefix determines if String p is a prefix of String q."* Its use in the `<` comparison in ARC is to handle `"ABC" < "ABCD"` (which is true) and `"ABCD" < "ABC"` (which is false). Once the algorithm has ruled out one of the strings being a prefix of the other, it goes looking for where they no longer match so it can return the result of comparing the chars that don't match.

Comment: @Kevin - The IsStringPrefix question there is now *very* far afield from the question you posted and that I answered. For future questions, please post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

As the specification says in your link:

> The comparison x < y, where x and y are values, produces true, false, or undefined (which indicates that at least one operand is NaN). In addition to x and y the algorithm takes a Boolean flag named LeftFirst as a parameter. **The flag is used to control the order in which operations with potentially visible side-effects are performed upon x and y.** It is necessary because ECMAScript specifies left to right evaluation of expressions. The default value of LeftFirst is true and indicates that the x parameter corresponds to an expression that occurs to the left of the y parameter's corresponding expression. If LeftFirst is false, the reverse is the case and operations must be performed upon y before x.

For an example of such a thing, consider two objects being compared. For `<` to be performed on them, both need to be coerced to primitives first, and this primitive coercion is permitted to have side effects which *could* affect the coercion of the other object. It would be *weird*, but it's syntactically possible, so the specification needs to specify what must happen in such a situation.

Keep in mind that there's *only one* version of Abstract Relational Comparison, and that's for `expr1 < expr2`. There is no separate version for `expr1 > expr2`. The `LeftFirst` flag is used when invoking Abstract Relational Comparison to indicate which of the expressions should be evaluated first, so that the left-to-right order of operations is preserved.

Here's an example:

```js
let val = 1;
const obj1 = {
  valueOf() {
    val++;
    return val;
  }
};
const obj2 = {
  valueOf() {
    val++;
    return val;
  }
};
console.log(obj1 < obj2);
```

Expressions are evaluated left-to-right. `obj1` is evaluated before `obj2`, so after extracting the primitives, `obj1` is less than `obj2`.

```js
let val = 1;
const obj1 = {
  valueOf() {
    val++;
    return val;
  }
};
const obj2 = {
  valueOf() {
    val++;
    return val;
  }
};
console.log(obj2 > obj1);
```

The `obj2 > obj1` actually invokes Abstract Relational Comparison `obj1 < obj2`, with `LeftFirst` of `false`. As a result, the right side, `obj2` is evaluated first, because it comes first in the source code.

Intuitively, with left-to-right evaluation, we'd expect

```
obj2 > obj1
```

to result in

```
// evaluate obj2, increment val
2 > obj1

// evaluate obj1, increment val
2 > 3
```

resulting in `false`.

If it weren't for such a flag, the example above would result in `obj1` being evaluated first, and the result would be that `obj1` would be less than `obj2`, and the result of the comparison would be `true`. But this is not desirable: the expressions should be evaluated left-to-right.

Comment: can you give me an explanation about why the `<=` operator is evaluated `LeftFirst` equal to `false` both `<` operator and `<=` operator have a similar typeof symbol like `<` only with one diiference the `<=` operator is having an extra equal to sign `=` but why the `<=` operator is evaluated with `LeftFirst` being `false` similarly if you take the `>` operator it's evaluated `LeftFirst` being `false` but the `>=` operator is evaluated `LeftFirst` being `true` can you give me a clear explanation like the one you gave above why `>=` is `LeftFirst` true and why `<=` is `LeftFirst` false

Comment: Whatever value comes first in the source code gets evaluated first. In the case of `lval <= rval`, because the comparison is sent to Abstract Relational Comparison in *reverse* order (`rval < lval`), `LeftFirst` is `false` so that `lval` gets evaluated first. For `lval >= rval`, because the comparison performed is `lval < rval`, `LeftFirst` defaults to `true`, so that the `lval` will be evaluated first as desired.

Comment: so do you mean the `>=` operator is always evaluated `LeftFirst` being `true`

Comment: Yes, because the operation performed for `lval >= rval` is `lval < rval`, so to keep the proper order, leftFirst is true there. Same sort of thing for the other permutations - whatever the situation, Abstract Relational Comparison is called such that the element on the left in the source code is evaluated first.

Comment: Thank you very much i got to know why if `<` operator is `LeftFirst` `true` then why `<=` is also not `LeftFirst` `true` and why `if` `>` operator is `LeftFirst` false the `>=` operator is also not `LeftFirst` `false`