# What exactly the "LeftFirst" Boolean Flag is in "Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm" in ECMAScript?

Tags: javascript, order-of-execution, relational-operators, ecmascript-2020

Can someone explain what exactly the `LeftFirst` Boolean Flag is in `Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm` in `ECMAScript`? I know that there is only one operator `<` handling all other relational operators like `>`, `>=`, `<=` as mentioned in the ECMAScript specification in [Abstract Relational Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)
using the `LeftFirst` Boolean Flag for, and example: when we write and run an operation like `10 > 5` the `LeftFirst Boolean Flag` becomes `false`, and the left operand `10` is moved to the right side where the operand `5` is, and the right operand `5` is moved to the left side where the operand `10` earlier was, and the `>` operator becomes `<` operator and at last something like this is executed `5 < 10`, but now my question is: when executing `5 < 10` I must know whether what operand gets evaluated first, is it the operand `5` or is it the operand `10`? I'm asking this because they have not mentioned about this in the `ECMAScript` specification in the [Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

and I must know why the `>=` is executed with `LeftFirst` true and why the `<=` is executed with `LeftFirst` false. Pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input values `x` and `y` in the algorithm description are expected to be fully evaluated before those steps begin. The flag is so that the operations like `ToPrimitive()` happen in the proper order.

For example, `x` and `y` might be object references. The `ToPrimitive()` operation will call either `.toString()` or `.valueOf()` in order to perform the comparison operation. Either of those functions might have side-effects, so the flag makes sure that the operations in the right order according to what the source code actually looks like.

A "side-effect" is a change to program state that happens in a function call. A `toString()` function can change anything that any other function can change: properties of the object, global variables, anything. The rule makes sure that those changes happen in the correct order (left-side changes before right-side changes), no matter what the algorithm does to "flip" the operands.

Comment: what do you mean by side effects

Comment: @user13104441 I'll extend the answer

Comment: so you mean that this rule doesnt apply for primitives in ecmaScript for and example `10 > 5` its executed like `5 < 10` and now you mean the number `5` is evaluated first before number `10`

Comment: @user13104441 yes it doesn't make any difference for primitive values because they're already primitive values; the `ToPrimitive` operation doesn't do anything in that case.

Comment: what about objects i mean what will happen if we compare two objects like `obj1 > obj2` this is also executed `LeftFirst` being `false` like `obj2 < obj1` so in this case which object will get evaluated first is it the `obj1` or is it the `obj2`